# Sticky menu jumping to top immediately on scroll

Tags: sticky

I have a sticky menu which is jumping to the top of the screen as soon as you start scrolling the page. I only want it to stick when the user starts to scroll past it.

I've tried amending the code but with my limited knowledge I can't figure out how to fix it. Please can anyone help?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<style>
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    z-index: 1;
}

.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold
}

    .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #880d53;
        color: white;
    }

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

    .sticky + .content {
        padding-top: 60px;
    }

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }

    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
    #myTopnav {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

main.page-wrapper > .container:first-child {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
}


@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #myTopnav {
        position: relative;
    }

        #myTopnav.sticky {
            position: fixed;
        }

    body.showMenu #myTopnav a {
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
    }

    body #myTopnav a:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }

    body #myTopnav a:last-child {
        display: block !important;
    }

    body.showMenu #myTopnav a:not(:first-child) {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        text-align: left;
    }

    body.showMenu .topnav .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
    .topnav {
        position: relative;
    }

        .topnav.sticky {
            position: fixed;
        }
}

</style>
```

```
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("#myTopnav a.icon").click(function() {
      jQuery("body").toggleClass("showMenu");
  
      myFunction();
      });
  });
</script>

<!-- Script add burger menu on mobile -->
<script>
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Script to make menu sticky -->
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var myTopnav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
var sticky = myTopnav.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    myTopnav.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    myTopnav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

<script
  src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  var waitForEl = function(selector, callback, count) {
    if (jQuery(selector).length) {
      callback();
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if(!count) {
          count=0;
        }
        count++;
        if(count<10) {
          waitForEl(selector,callback,count);
        } else {return;}
      }, 400);
    }
  };

  var selector = 'body:not(.body-editor) .Theme-CollectionSectionSection .Theme-Layer-Gallery-List';


  waitForEl(selector, function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.Theme-Layer-Gallery-Item a').removeAttr('target');
    }, 400);
  });
</script>
```